# Adding JSON-LD but avoiding duplicate content?

Tags: html, json-ld

I've just found out about JSON-LD and I'm having trouble understanding how I'm supposed to avoid duplicate content. From what I understand I'm supposed to duplicate my content in a script placed somewhere on the page. In order for search engines to pick it up as structured data. Is this correct? Does anyone have a tip on how to handle or avoid duplicate data?

Comment: What issue related to duplicate content are you concerned about?

Comment: From what I understand in order to get structured data show up in Google you need to add a copy of your content in JSON-LD in your html file. Is there no other way of doing this then duplicating your content?

Comment: Not when using JSON-LD, apart from a few cases where xpath and cssSelector are supported. Those cases may expand in the future. An alternate is to mark up with microdata, which is added as part of your html content.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath do you have an example that you could post as an answer?

Comment: Not at this time. It does not look like xpath and cssSelector got much use.